# To find the longest connected element in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How can I find the longest connected element in a array of size 4*5. Two element is said to be connected if the value is same horizontally or vertically. the value is not same if present diagonally.

The array is

```
        [ B C D A D

          D C D A B

          D C C C A

          C D B A B ]
```

Here the longest sequence is 5 and its for C

This could be sorted out using Longest Common Subsequence algorthim, but dont know how to exactly implement it.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Where precisely are the six connected Cs? If diagonal connections are disallowed, I am only seeing five.

Comment: Sorry, yeah its five...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to check for groups of connected elements.

That's the algorithm I would implement:

```
for each field of the array
    when the field is not marked as checked
        use flood-fill to get the connected group the field belongs to
        for each field which is part of the group
            mark it as checked        
        when this group got more fields than the larges known group
            this group is now the largest known group
```